# Can't get MozTransform to work with Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to get the zoom function for Firefox to work using javascript but no luck, what am I doing wrong?

```
    function zoomIn() {
        document.getElementById('increaseWrapper').style['MozTransform'] = 'scale(1.5)';
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like it should work. Take a look [at this](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/17/animate-css-transforms-firefox-webkit.html) ... maybe it will help?

Comment: It works fine for me.  Have you made sure that your "zoomIn()" function is actually being called?

Comment: <input id="btnZoomIn" type="button" value="Zoom In" onclick="zoomIn()" />

Comment: [Here is the jsfiddle that works for me in Firefox.](http://jsfiddle.net/r26EZ/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work perfectly find in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/t6hYu/) in Firefox 6.

Remember, 'MozTransform' only applies to Mozilla derived browsers.  Safari and Opera and others have their own name for that attribute until it becomes an endorsed standard.

If you're trying your code in mozilla 4+ browser, then there must be something else wrong with your code because what you have disclosed in your question works fine in the right browser with the right HTML.

Have you checked your browser's error console or debugger console to see if you're experiencing an javascript errors that might be keeping your code from executing?

Comment: unfortunately, html5 (now HTML), has been declared a live document.  a "living standard" if you will.  like nailing jello to a wall.  Does this mean we live with browser hacks forever?

Comment: You can complain if you want or you can just understand the state of the browsers and deal with that.  Right now, if you want to use CSS3 transitions or animations, you HAVE to use browser-specific CSS directives.  That will go away with time just like moz-opacity has disappeared, but until you're ready to drop support for the current versions of Chrome, Mozilla, Safari and Opera you'll have to code the browser-specific CSS directives.  I'm not arguing this is the best way for it to work, but it is what it is.